# Spring-MyBatis Design

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am going to start a project with spring-mybatis and a little bit confused about project design. Normally I am using **Dao&DaoImpl** style (Dao for interfece and DaoImpl for JDBC implementation) but as I've seen at mybatis projects there is **Mapper&Service** style. Can't I use Dao for Mapper and DaoImpl for Service? Or they have different usages so I should use all of them?

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it for me is Dao (interface) and Dao.xml (mybatis stuff, which does the queries and the mapping)